# Sign-in to Developer Portal not working on Premium SKU over AppGw with AzureAD

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-api-management, azure-application-gateway

We operate an API Management instance with these parameters

- Premium SKU
- internal VNET mode
- exposed externally over Application Gateway
- authentication with our corporate Azure AD

From within the VNET and w/o Application Gateway authentication to the Developer Portal works perfectly.

When trying to sign-in externally over Application Gateway, it almost always fails and browser is redirected to the sign-in page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spending hours together with MS Support tracing the issue, it turns out that "connection affinity for login traffic is not maintained for Azure AD or Facebook authentication".

This left these options for us

- downgrade to Developer SKU (so that VNET can still be used)
- switch from AzureAD to APIM Developer Portal built-in Forms authentication
- not expose the Developer Portal over Application Gateway externally and find other ways (e.g. VPN) to connect

As none of these is a real solution for our use case, [I posted fixing this problem on user voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/20450122-handle-connection-affinity-correctly-for-azure-ad).